# windbg: da without print newline

Tags: debugging, memory, windbg

When I use commands like `da [eax]`, it usually print the data in multiple lines:

```
059f20d0  "..."
059f20f0  "..."
059f2110  "..."
```

Although there's no `\r` or `\n` inside, it is always multiple lines.

Is it possible to print this null-terminated string in a single line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `.printf` instead of `da`.

For example: `.printf "Foo: %ma\\n", 0x059f20d0`

Note:

1. There's no `%s` in WinDbg `.printf`. Use `%ma` for ASCII strings and `%mu` for Unicode (UTF-16) strings.
2. **No parentheses** around the arguments of `.printf`
3. Double backslash - one is the usual backslash for `printf`-style `\n` and the second one is because the WinDbg command Interpreter parses these codes and we want `.printf` to get the `\n` rather than the newline character itself.

Comment: Is it possible to append to a file as well?

Answer (score 0):

.logopen x://foo.xxx
da /c 256  address/len / range 
.logclose

**standard width**

```
0:000> da 5ca608
005ca608  "        <dpiAware  xmlns="http:/"
005ca628  "/schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/"
005ca648  "WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>"
005ca668  "..    </windowsSettings>..</appl"
005ca688  "ication>..</assembly>.."
```

**custom width**

```
0:000> da /c 98 5ca608
005ca608  "        <dpiAware  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">true</dpiAware>..    </windowsSettings>..</application>..</assembly>.."
```